# Get datepicker defaultdate from string/django object

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, datepicker

I am a total (like no-experience-whatsoever) noob in jquery and Javascript, and what I would like to do is the following:

I pass an article-object to my template that has date-information stored in it.
I can access and display that information with `{{ article.pubdate }}`.
Is it possible to set the `defaultDate` option of datepicker to the article date?
How would I go about that?

Thanks for any pointers!

**Update**:
Some more information about `{{ article.pubdate }}`:
It is a datetime object. The display format of the string can be edited, so `{{ article.pubdate|date:"Y-m-d"}}` gives a date like 2013-07-27.

**Update 2**:
I display the article date on the page like this:

```
<div id="article-pubdate">
        {{ article.pubdate|date:"Y-m-d" }}
</div>
```

This gives me `2013-07-27` as a string displayed on the page.
After reading around I tried the following approach to get that string into datepicker like so:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
      var a = $("#article-pubdate").text();
      var the_date = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", a);
      $(".datepicker input").datepicker({
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          yearRange: '1990:2013',
          defaultDate: the_date,
      });
  });
</script>
```

But this doesn't work, why?

**Update 2**:
If I set `defaultDate` like so:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".datepicker input" ).datepicker({
         dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
         changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
         yearRange:'1990:2013',
         defaultDate:"2001-01-01"
    });
  });
</script>
```

it works absolutely fine. Is there any way to pass the date info directly into datepicker?

Comment: And what does `article.pubdate` look like? Is it a string, if so in what format, is a Date object, or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set default date using [setDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)

You need to use this after initialization of datepicker, for that you need to pass date Object

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker(datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: '1990:2013',
  });

$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date($("#article-pubdate").text().replace(/\-/g, ',')));
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I get `{{article.pubdate}}`or the string of it into `new Date()`?

Comment: 1. We need to extract the date from div 2. we need to replace the "-" with "," with replace(). i have updated that in ans

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work :(
Updated my question though, maybe that helps?

Comment: have u tried with "setDate" i didnt found in your updated ans, and for the working example  [please check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kartheek527/QjN8R/3/)

Comment: The fiddle did it for me, I forgot to change your '#datepicker' to my '.datepicker input' :D
Awesome, thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, one problem has come up: I can't change the input now. The input field gets set correctly, but I can't change the input field, as datepicker always reverts to the `setDate` value. Any way to change this?

Comment: oh damn, my fault, sorry!