# How to Populate jQuery Datepicker widget from Django template variable?

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm having trouble populating a jQuery Datepicker widget with the value of a Django template variable.  I have the following model and form fields:

```
# models.py
class Meeting(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()

# forms.py
class AddMeetingForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
```

In my template, the datepicker widget acts on the 'date' input tag.  I want the default date format to be "mm-dd-yyyy", e.g. "12-30-2016".  I'm telling the datepicker what date format to expect and then I pass the meeting object to the template and print out its date field using a date filter to convert it to the desired format:

```
# edit_meeting.html
<div>
    <label for="id_date">Date</label>
    {{ form.date.errors }}
    <input type="text" name="date" id="id_date"/>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( '#id_date' ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
    });
    $( '#id_date' ).datepicker(
            'setDate', {{ meeting.date|date:"mm-dd-Y" }})
});
</script>
```

The jQuery [formatDate utility](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) defines how dates are formatted for this widget while Django's [date filter](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#date) specifies how Django dates are formatted.

When I print the value in my PostgreSQL database, I see the field has the value "2016-12-30" and when I print the meeting.date field to my console from inside the view that renders the template, I also see that its value is "2016-12-30".  However, the datepicker widget is populating the field with the value "06-30-2006".  Am I setting up the jQuery Datepicker widget incorrectly?  I don't have much experience with jQuery and it feels like that's where the problem is.

**UPDATE**

Per another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897835/get-datepicker-defaultdate-from-string-django-object) I tried to write the date to a hidden field in my page and then reference that the field directly, but this doesn't pre-populate the date field with the party.date value either .

```
<div id="meeting_date" class="hidden">
    {{ meeting.date }}
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    var meeting_date = $("#meeting_date").text();
    $( '#id_date' ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
    });
    $( '#id_date' ).datepicker(
            'setDate', $.datepicker.parseDate( 'yy-mm-dd', new Date(meeting_date) )
    );
});
</script>
```

**SOLUTION**

As gaetanoM showed, the key to inserting a Django template variable into a jQuery function is to surround the variable with single or double quotes.  In this case I also had to apply a date filter.  The Django date filter "Y-m-d" says that the value of the date being passed in from Django has a format of 'yy-mm-dd' (e.g. "2016-12-30").  Once jQuery knows what the 'yy', 'mm', and 'dd' "pieces" of the date are via the parseDate function, we display them in the widget using jQuery's default date format 'mm/dd/yy'.  One thing I don't understand is if jQuery's default date format is 'mm/dd/yy', why do you have to explicity specify it in the first three lines of the function?  In any event, I'm just glad it's working.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( '#id_date' ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    });
    $( '#id_date' ).datepicker(
            'setDate', $.datepicker.parseDate( 'yy-mm-dd', '{{ party.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}' )
    );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [django date template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

you can change:

```
'setDate', {{ meeting.date|date:"mm-dd-Y" }})
```

to:

```
'setDate', "{{ meeting.date|date:"m-d-Y" }}")
```

***OLD ANSWER***

You defined the ***dateFormat*** as ***'mm-dd-yy'*** .

So, according to [setDate( date )](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate), you can pass a string in the defined format or a date.
Because the formats are different you can use ***$.datepicker.parseDate( format, value, options )*** in order to convert the date string to the right date value:

```js
$( '#id_date' ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
});
$( '#id_date' ).datepicker(
  'setDate', $.datepicker.parseDate( 'yy-mm-dd', '2016-12-30' )
);
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<p>Date: <input type="text" id="id_date"></p>
```

Comment: I see what you're saying and if I hard code my template as you've shown, I get the same result.  But this doesn't answer my question from the perspective of passing a Django variable to a jQuery method.  If I replace your '2016-12-30' string with {{ party.date }}, the jQuery method doesn't work.  I believe it's because the "{{" and "}}" delimiters are confusing jQuery.  I think the crux of the problem is, how do you pass a Django template variable to a jQuery method from within a Django template?

Comment: Is there a way in jQuery to replace the "{" and "}" characters with their ASCII equivalents "123" and "125"?  Can I just hardcode it some how like "&#123&#123" party.date "&#125&#125"?

Comment: Sorry Dave, but the {} chars must be handled directly from django. Yes, you can replace these chars as usual in html.

Comment: @Dave can you take a look to [django to js variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript)?